# Configure Unity. Error "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'UserStore`1'."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

I'm working on app with MVC5, EF 6 and using ASP.NET Identity. I am using dependency injection Unity to resolve my classes.
My giude was this blog post: https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/

Аfter doing everything from the article, and when i first run the code, it gaves me: **The type Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1[[AppMVC.Models.ApplicationUser, AppMVC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (ApplicationDbContext).** error on this line in UnityConfig.RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container) static method:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below.
            // Make sure to add a Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
            // container.LoadConfiguration();

            // TODO: Register your type's mappings here.
            // container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();

            container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>();
            container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
            container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            container.RegisterType<IBaseService<Picture>, PictureService>();
            container.RegisterType<IPictureService, PictureService>();
            container.RegisterType<IBaseService<UserExt>, UserExtService>();
            container.RegisterType<IUserExtService, UserExtService>();

            container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
            new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
            container.RegisterType<AccountController>();
            container.RegisterType<ManageController>();
            container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        }
```

Specifically in

```
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));
```

After that I changed it to:

```
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

And the error disappeared. When i try to login through my app and hit the 'Log in' button i entered Login method in AccountController:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then when I go in

```
var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

I immediately end up in

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (userManager != null)
            {
                userManager.Dispose();
                userManager = null;
            }

            if (signInManager != null)
            {
                signInManager.Dispose();
                signInManager = null;
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

With error:
[image]

My AccountController's constructor looks like this

```
[Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private  ApplicationUserManager userManager;
        private  ApplicationSignInManager signInManager;
        private readonly IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        }
}
```

The same error is thrown when i try to register new user:
[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm missing in my code?
Thank you, in advance!